# SELECT all at once

Tags: sql

I want to select patient_id and date difference from below table:

```
p_id    TreatmentDate
15      2008-05-01
15      2008-05-03
15      2008-05-05
15      2008-05-07
16      2008-05-01
16      2008-05-03
16      2008-05-05
16      2008-05-09
16      2008-05-11
17      2008-05-03
17      2008-05-05
17      2008-05-07
```

I want to have this result:

```
p_id      Day Difference
15        6 Days
16        10 Days
17        4 Days
```

Do you have any offer that can generate this result in sql statement?

Comment: How do you calculate 8 days for P_id = 16?

Comment: It should be 15, I think he got confused, everything else matches expectations.

Comment: These datas not from my database, i wrote quickly. Thats why i made mistake. If you didn't understand what i tried to ask, please forgive me.It is my fault. I am so sad now. How did i make this kind of mistake i can't believe. Please accept my apologises.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should work in general

```
select p_id, max(TreatmentDate) - min(TreatmentDate) from 
patientsTable group by p_id
```

more specifically, for MSSQL Server

```
select p_id, DATEDIFF(D, MIN(TreatmentDate), MAX(TreatmentDate)) from 
patientsTable group by p_id
```

Comment: Correct answere. But in SQL Server, I would use the DATEDIFF function:

SELECT
   p_id
   ,[Day Difference] = DATEDIFF(D, MIN(TreatmentDate), MAX(TreatmentDate)) 
FROM PatientsTable 
GROUP BY p_id

Comment: Would you please tell me, if i group by p_id, how dbms access to TreatmentDate? As you know if i group p_id the result would be only 15,16,17. There willn't be TreatmentDate will it?

Comment: you have to do a grouping function with the treatmentdate column (like sum(), max(), min(), avg(), etc.). In this case, you will have a number representing the substraction of the maximum date from the minimum date for each p_id.

Comment: I think with my english, i can't ask what i want.But want to try last time.What is happening when we execute "SELECT p_id,max(TreatmentDate) FROM table GROUP BY p_id;" ? I think but i'm not sure: 1- Selecting p_id and TreatmentDate. 2- While grouping them (them = p_id and TreatmentDate even we dond't add it) 3- Running Min function to find the value for second row of select result. 4- Then generating new table and to send back.
I don't know in which order it is processing but if you know exact result and order please tell me.
PS:I know why we are grouping and how we can.

Comment: h, you are asking how do databases implement group by. I think this is database dependent and I also think this is material for a separate question. The question you want to ask is "how do databases implement group by?" In that question you should explain you know what group by does but that you want to know how is it done in the various database engines. As an appetizer you can watch the execution plan

Answer (score 3):

**MS SQL Server:**

```
SELECT 
    p_id, 
    STR(DATEDIFF(DAY, MIN(TreatmentDate), MAX(TreatmentDate))) + ' Days' AS DayDifference
FROM 
    table 
GROUP BY 
    p_id
```

Comment: This is assuming the OP is using SQL Server.

Comment: @Vinko: Based on the tags from his other questions, I assumed SQL Server.

Comment: It probably is, but consider the other readers of this question. Somebody else might try using DATEDIFF in MySQL, for example. It's better to warn readers of specific solutions.

Answer (score 2):

MS SQL:

```
select
    p_id,
    datediff(d, min(TreatmentDate), max(TreatmentDate)) AS DayDifference
from 
    patientsTable
group by
    p_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
SELECT p_id, CONCAT(max(TreatmentDate) - min(TreatmentDate),' Days') as "Day Difference" 
FROM
patient_info 
GROUP BY p_id;
```

Given this schema/data:

```
CREATE TABLE patient_info (
p_id INT,
TreatmentDate DATE
);
INSERT INTO patient_info 
VALUES 
(15,'2008-05-01'),
(15,'2008-05-03'),
(15,'2008-05-05'),
(15,'2008-05-07'),
(16,'2008-05-01'),
(16,'2008-05-03'),
(16,'2008-05-05'),
(16,'2008-05-09'),
(17,'2008-05-03'),
(17,'2008-05-05'),
(17,'2008-05-07');

+------+----------------+
| p_id | Day Difference |
+------+----------------+
|   15 | 6 Days         | 
|   16 | 8 Days         | 
|   17 | 4 Days         | 
+------+----------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Please let me know if you need more help.

Comment: And this is assuming the OP is using MySQL

Comment: You test data comprises only 11 rows. The OP's test data comprises 12 rows. You are missing the row 
p_id = 16, TreatmentDate = 2008-05-11.