# How do aggregates (group by) work on SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How does SQL Server implement group by clauses (aggregates)?

As inspiration, take the execution plan of [this question's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465827/select-at-onece) query:

```
select p_id, DATEDIFF(D, MIN(TreatmentDate), MAX(TreatmentDate)) from 
patientsTable group by p_id
```

Before query data, simple select statement and its execution plan is this:
[image]

After retrieving the data with the query and execution plan:
[image]

Comment: I don't really get this question

Comment: `@op` asks to explain how aggregates and aggregations work in `SQL Server`. This is a nice and perfectly valid question.

Comment: @Quassnoi, THANK YOU VERY MUCH. I can't tell you how much i tried to ask this question. Just want to learn what is happening behind of scene.

Comment: I hope you don't mind my editing, uzay95

Comment: In your case the `Hash Aggregate` is used.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Usually it's a `Stream Aggregate` or a `Hash Aggregate`.

- `Stream aggregate` sorts the resultset, scans it and returns every new value (not equal to the last in scan). It allows to keep but one set of the aggregate state variables.
- `Hash aggregate` builds a hash table from the resultset. Each entry keeps the aggregate state variables which are initialized on hash miss and updated on hash hit.

Let's see how `AVG` works. It needs two state variables: `sum` and `count`

```
grouper  value
1        4
1        3
2        8
1        7
2        1
1        2
2        6
2        3
```

#### Stream Aggregate

1. First, it needs to sort the values:

   ```
   grouper  value
   1        4
   1        3
   1        7
   1        2
   2        8
   2        1
   2        6
   2        3
   ```

   - Then, it keeps one set of state variables, initialized to `0`, and scans the sorted resultset:

     grouper  value  sum   count
     -- Entered 
     -- Variables:    0    0
     1        4       4    1
     1        3       7    2
     1        7      14    3
     1        2      16    4
     -- Group change. Return the result and reinitialize the variables
     -- Returning 1, 4
     -- Variables:    0    0
     2        8       8    1
     2        1       9    2
     2        6      15    3
     2        3      18    4
     -- Group change. Return the result and reinitialize the variables
     -- Returning 2, 4.5
     -- End

#### Hash aggregate

- Just scanning the values and keeping the state variables in the hash table:

  ```
  grouper  value
  -- Hash miss. Adding new entry to the hash table
  --             [1] (0,  0)
  -- ... and updating it:
  1        4     [1] (4,  1)
  -- Hash hit. Updating the entry:
  1        3     [1] (7,  2)
  -- Hash miss. Adding new entry to the hash table
  --             [1] (7,  2)  [2] (0, 0)
  -- ... and updating it:
  2        8     [1] (7,  2)  [2] (8,  1)
  1        7     [1] (14, 3)  [2] (8,  1)
  2        1     [1] (14, 3)  [2] (9,  2)
  1        2     [1] (16, 4)  [2] (9,  2)
  2        6     [1] (16, 4)  [2] (15, 3)
  2        3     [1] (16, 4)  [2] (18, 4)
  -- Scanning the hash table and returning the aggregated values
  -- 1   4
  -- 2   4.5
  ```

Usually, sort is faster if the resultset is already ordered (like, the values come out of the index or a resultset sorted by the previous operation).

Hash is faster is the resultset is not sorted (hashing is faster than sorting).

`MIN` and `MAX` are special cases, since they don't require scanning the whole group: only the first and the last value of the aggregated column within the group.

Unfortunately, `SQL Server`, unlike most other systems, cannot utilize this efficiently, since it's not good in doing `INDEX SKIP SCAN` (jumping over distinct index keys).

While simple `MAX` and `MIN` (without `GROUP BY` clause) use a `TOP` method if the index on the aggregated column is present, `MIN` and `MAX` with `GROUP BY` use same methods as other aggregate functions do.

Comment: The Microsoft Connect item about the skip scan: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/695044/implement-index-skip-scan

Comment: @Quassnoi Brilliant share, can you tell me which books do you read to gain this type of knowledge?

Answer (score 0):

AS i dont have table available i tried with my custom table PRICE

I defined Primary key = ID_PRICE

```
Select PRICE.ID_PRICE, Max(PRICE.COSTKVARH) - min(PRICE.COSTKVARH) from PRICE
GROUP BY PRICE.ID_PRICE
```

Plan:

PLAN (PRICE ORDER PK_PRICE)

Adapted plan:

PLAN (PRICE ORDER PK_PRICE)

In your case p_id is a primary key so the adapted plan will be first order of patientsTable based on p_id then grouping and difference calculation will happen..